# OpenFileDialog C# Asking for opening twice?

Tags: c#, telerik, openfiledialog

I have used a Telerik Browse Editor to open a file on my program. But for some reason it is asking me for the file twice. From the code below can anyone see why?

```
   private void radBrowseEditor1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            openFileDialog.Title = @"Open .HRM File";
            openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\mike\Desktop";
            openFileDialog.Filter = @"HRM files (*.hrm)|*.hrm|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
            openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

            }

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog.FileName, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
            {
                HRM.Active.Raw = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
   }
```

Probably something really simple. Pretty sure that code I used when I had a toolstrip before I installed Telerik and it worked fine.

Comment: Use the debugger, add breakpoints. Is ShowDialog() called twice?

Comment: Maybe you are calling `radBrowseEditor1_ValueChanged` twice. or assigned it to event handler twice.

Comment: In reply to both, no I can not find either of them called twice.

Comment: Is radBrowseEditor1 a radio button? If so, do you want to show the dialog only when the radio button is checked? If so to that, then the beginning of this event should be checking for that.

Comment: The browse editor is exactly like going to file and open.

Comment: What kind of control is radBrowseEditor1: a radio button, check box, button, text box? Is it a control on your form that you are clicking?

Comment: Yes. It has a ... Button then it opens the dialog. Just as if you would go to File and Click open on a toolstrip.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you're not answer my question.  I don't want to know what it has on it, I want to know what radBrowseEditor1 is.  This snippet for example, Dim txtMyTextBox as TextBox, txtMyTextBox is a TextBox.  I want to know what kind of control radBrowseEditor1 is.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=radbrowseeditor&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=979&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=RH1HVeG-MMXjas6jgIgI&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAg#imgrc=FkoSqfdVY86ReM%253A%3Bd-K9KkmZkTUTZM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.telerik.com%252Fhelp%252Fwinforms%252Fmedia%252Feditors-browse-editor-getting-started001.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.telerik.com%252Fhelp%252Fwinforms%252Feditors-browse-editor-getting-started.html%3B306%3B161

Comment: @user2913240 after the radBrowseEditor opens a file, does the value change?

Comment: It adds the path into the editor yes. and loads data into a datagridview. Just wondering why I have to load the file twice. As soon as the first openfiledialog closes another one opens.

Answer (score 0):

After reading this, http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/editors-browse-editor-working-with.html, it seems like you don't even need to bother with the openFileDialog.  It does look like you should check that the value is not blank.

```
private void radBrowseEditor1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(radBrowseEditor1.Value.ToString()))
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(radBrowseEditor1.Value.ToString(), System.Text.Encoding.Default))
        {
            HRM.Active.Raw = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That does not work due to the rest of my code and the way it is calculating data from the file it loads in.

Comment: @user2913240 How does your original solution work, with exception of a dialog window opening twice?

Comment: That is the code at the top, thats how the solution works. And then it reads data line by line from a txt file and places it into a datagridview. The same code I used before for toolstripmenuItem_Clicked and it worked perfect.

Comment: @user2913240 Is the DialogType property of your radBrowseEditor1 set for OpenFileDialog?  If so, I definitely don't understand the difference between having the OpenFileDialog code in the ValueChanged event and not having it.  What is HRM.Active.Raw doing once it's assigned reader.ReadToEnd()?

Comment: Yeah ive realised what has happened, the code delcaring the OpenFileDialog is not neccesary! Because the DialogType is set to OpenFile Dialog. But I am just wondering how to implement the streamreader the same when deleting the filedialog code.

Comment: @user2913240 So the Value property of the radBrowseEditor1 is not the same as the openFileDialog.FileName from your original solution?

Comment: No, you dont need anything in the method in order to open a file with a browseeditor. So I have no idea what to use for the StreamReader because radBrowseEditor1.FileName does not work

Comment: @user2913240 Why can't you use the Value property of radBrowseEditor1?